# How to place multiple lines of text in the headers in ConTeXt?

Tags: header-footer, line-breaking, context, context-mkiv

I am using this to place headers within my document:

```
\setupheadertexts[{Birds of South America \getmarking[chapter]}][][][]
```

I tried to place the title on a different line, using `\\`, `\crlf`, `\vskip`, `\frame`, but all of these commands are either ignored or give errors.

I tried this:

```
\setupheadertexts[{Birds of South America \\ \getmarking[chapter]}][][][]
\starttext
    \chapter{Bolivia}
\stoptext
```

I also tried this:

```
\setupheadertexts[{\framed{Birds of South America \\ \getmarking[chapter]}}][][][]
\starttext
    \chapter{Bolivia}
\stoptext
```

It should look like this, with "Bolivia" on a second line.

```
Birds of South America
Bolivia
```

How can I have headers with multiple lines in ConTeXt?

Comment: Did you try to use a `parbox` inside it?

Comment: `\parbox` seems to be a LaTeX command.

Comment: In these layout elements the vertical space commands are suppressed, see [``page-txt.tex``](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/page-txt.mkvi#l299).
If you must, you can hack your way around this limitation like this:
``\let\forceline\crlf
\setupheadertexts[{\framed[align=left]{foo\forceline bar}}][pagenumber]
``

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, the header texts are a `\hbox`. To get multiple lines, you need a `\vbox`. The easiest way to get a `\vbox` in ConTeXt is to use `\framed[align=normal]`. Here is an example demonstrating that:

```
\setupheadertexts[\setups{headertext}]

\startsetups headertext
  \framed[frame=off, align=normal]
      {Birds of South America \\ \getmarking[chapter]}
\stopsetups

\starttext

\startchapter[title={First chapter}]
  \input knuth
\stopchapter

\startchapter[title={Second chapter}]
  \input knuth
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```